# Split result on postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I need to send a query to postgresql database which result has  a great numbrer  of rows and exceedes the connection limit of php, has postgres any way to split the result in small pieces?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is deprecated and no longer maintained. You should plan your upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 10) **now**

Comment: open cursor and fetch it. also how connection limit affects the amount of data sent?..